# What is the equivalent of hg up -C in git

Tags: git, mercurial

I want to get the current head of my git repo destroying all changes made and erasing additional files in the working copy.

Comment: `hg up -c` is the same as `--check`. Did you mean `-C` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you are looking for something like this. Be careful! This potentially erases things that you cannot get back.

```
git reset --hard

git clean -fx
```

Comment: You can use -e on git-clean if theres a specific file you don't want to erase. If I recall, it can't be safely used with -x though (I believe it has no effect in that case). (This may only be in `master` of git.git though)

Comment: You might want to add the `-d` option to `git clean` - that'll make it remove whole untracked directories, which otherwise it'd ignore. You also might not always want to delete ignored files (`-x`).